# Lambda functions with wildcards in Kotlin

Tags: java, generics, lambda, kotlin

I was looking at the examples provided by Google and came across this line

```
private final ArrayMap<Class, Callable<? extends ViewModel>> creators;
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to convert that `Callable<? extends ViewModel>` into a lambda in Kotlin

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT:

```
class ViewModelFactory(appComponent: AppComponent) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private val creators: ArrayMap<Class<*>, () -> ViewModel> = ArrayMap()

    init {
        creators.put(DashboardViewModel::class.java, { appComponent.getDashboardViewModel() })
    }

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>?): T = creators[modelClass]?.invoke() as T
}
```

In the code above, I am getting an unchecked cast lint message in my IDE. 
Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean saying 'convert Callable into a lambda'? Do you want to convert Callable to Kotlin functional type, `() -> ViewModel`?

Comment: i have edited the question to show my problem, rather than my "solution"

Comment: No way to avoid it. You can't prove that given creator returns an object of type `T`. Such things remain with unchecked casts. Note also, that if `creators[modelClass]` is null, whole expression `creators[modelClass]?.invoke()` will be null, and casting it to non-null type will throw an exception.

Comment: you're right. silly me, thanks